# CardLayout with buttons that change the cards

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, cardlayout

I am trying to write a short program that has a home page with title and 4 buttons, 3 of which will leave the home screen and go to a new page where you can input information accordingly.  I started by using a drag and drop editor but have found through forums i should be using cardlayout instead i have looked over the oracle tutorial but i want to use buttons to change cards not a combobox.  Is that possible.

here is the code from the tutorial what part would i need to change to make a button the action button that changes screens.

thanks,

```
package layout;

/*
 * CardLayoutDemo.java
 *
 */
import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CardLayoutDemo implements ItemListener {
    JPanel cards; //a panel that uses CardLayout
    final static String BUTTONPANEL = "Card with JButtons";
    final static String TEXTPANEL = "Card with JTextField";

public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
    //Put the JComboBox in a JPanel to get a nicer look.
    JPanel comboBoxPane = new JPanel(); //use FlowLayout
    String comboBoxItems[] = { BUTTONPANEL, TEXTPANEL };
    JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(comboBoxItems);
    cb.setEditable(false);
    cb.addItemListener(this);
    comboBoxPane.add(cb);

    //Create the "cards".
    JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
    card1.add(new JButton("Button 1"));
    card1.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
    card1.add(new JButton("Button 3"));

    JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
    card2.add(new JTextField("TextField", 20));

    //Create the panel that contains the "cards".
    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    cards.add(card1, BUTTONPANEL);
    cards.add(card2, TEXTPANEL);

    pane.add(comboBoxPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
    cl.show(cards, (String)evt.getItem());
}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event dispatch thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardLayoutDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    CardLayoutDemo demo = new CardLayoutDemo();
    demo.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
    try {
        //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

    //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: `"Is that possible?"` -- of course. There's no magic about comboboxes that limit use of CardLayout to these guys. `"here is the code from the tutorial what part would i need to change to make a button the action button that changes screens."` -- you need to make the changes in your JButton's ActionListener. But rather than simply dump the tutorial code here, you should be showing us **your code attempt** to solve this. Else you're coming here way too early.

Comment: Edit: exactly as camickr states. 1+

Comment: I had coded quite a bit but scrtached it all i'll start it back up starting with cardlayout and repost if problems arise thank you

Comment: Good. As you can see, camickr and myself can only give you very general guidance, information you should have been able to glean for yourself by simply looking at the JButton tutorial, the CardLayout tutorial, and trying to put things together. You'll get much better and more specific help if you ask a much more specific question showing **your** code, and describing **your** problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but i want to use buttons to change cards not a combobox. Is that possible.

The tutorial uses an ItemListener for the combo box.

If you want to use buttons, then you would use an ActionListener.

The code in the `ActionListener` would basically be the same. That is you need to identify the card you want to change to.

```
cl.show(cards, BUTTONPANEL); // for example
```

Although since the button will probably display the name of the panel you want to switch to you could do something like:

```
cl.show(cards, event.getActionCommand());
```

The action command of the ActionEvent which is generated when you click on the button contains the text that is displayed on the button.